# Angular binding to selection of file input field?

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, angular-directive, input-field

I have a simple upload form and would like to bind the displayed filename to the value of the file input field `<input type="file">`, but for some reason it always shows some virtual filepath. How can the binding be improved to not have this behavior(only filename, like `selected.files[0].name`)?

Ideally the selected filename would be shown in the label for `#selected` right after the OS filechooser finishes. Another approach of mine is included in the comments (`*ngIf`), but it doesn't work either.

```
<form>
    <div class="justify-content-center">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Select image</span>
      </div>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="custom-file-input" id="selected" #selected (click)="message=''" >
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="selected">{{ selected.value }}</label>
<!--
        <div *ngIf="selected.files[0].name; then showFilename else showDefaultMsg"></div>
        <ng-template #showFilename>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="selected">{{ selected.files[0].name }}</label>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #showDefaultMsg>
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="selected">Choose file....</label>
        </ng-template>
-->
            </div>
        </div>
    <button [disabled]="!selected.value" id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpload(selected)">Upload</button>
        <div class="text-center" *ngIf="message">
            <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading....</span>
            </div>
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can reference the value like that and pick up changes. `selected` is an `HTMLInputElement`, not an `Observable<HTMLInputElement>` or any other thing that is going to emit the value on change.

In the below example, you'll see that the same setup with a text box shows what you would expect on page load, but doesn't actually pickup any changes to the input value.

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxkm3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You need to either use `ngModel`, `FormControl`, or just create an event for the `change` event.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  fileName = null;

  onFileChange(evt): void {
    this.fileName = evt.target.files[0].name;
  }
}
```

Template

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<input type="text" #myInput value="Init Text" />
<div>Input Text: {{myInput.value}}</div>
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
<div>name: {{fileName}}</div>
```